# Xcode 15.3 Archive and Direct Distribution of App fails during notarization: The signature of the binary is invalid / unsealed contents in root dir

Tags: xcode, macos, codesign, gomobile

- I have a macOS swift app that I ship via Archive / Direct Distribution / Export App (sign with Developer ID Certificate) -> Use notarytool within DMGCanvas.
- The app depends on a swift package that includes an XCFramework, that I build with `gomobile bind`.
- The notarytool returns: `The signature of the binary is invalid`
- The codesign verification command returns: `unsealed contents present in the root directory of an embedded framework`
- Before Xcode 15.3, this process was working as expected. The internal XCFramework wasn't preventing the app from being stopped by Gatekeeper with unsealed contents. I have not made any changes to this pipeline other than upgrade to Xcode 15.3 from 15.2

Core Issue: how does a code signed XCFramework added to a macOS app that is also code signed and ready for distribution, produce the error:
`The signature of the binary is invalid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**:
The Framework directory had an extraneous `Info.plist` file included in its directory. *Apple Docs [mention](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/placing_content_in_a_bundle)*:

> The framework’s root must contain only the Versions directory and symlinks. Don’t place any other content there. Doing so causes code-signing problems.

**Solution**:
remove the `Info.plist` in the macOS Framework root (this is not the same as the `Info.plist` that resides in the XCFramework root; keep that one). Once removed, Xcode codesign no longer throws an error.

**Conclusion**:
Follow Apple's instructions regarding XCFramework generation.

*Context of my workflow [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/66406), just in case anyone is curious*